# JQuery hide/show on ifram click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I was wondering what would the best way to add something that would hide a image when a iFrame was clicked, in this case a embedded YouTube video. I have a image that's on that's slighly over the iFrame and I'd like to hide it when the iFrame is clicked and show it again once it's clicked again after the first time. I'm not really experienced in JQuery but I know php well enough.

My image would be under something like:

```
<div class="picture">
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Add a click listener to the iframe and hide the picture.

```
$( "#myIframe" ).click(function() {
    $("#myImage").hide();
});
```

edit: since your pic only has a class, not id it would be `$(".picture").hide();`